# Ubuntu 18.04 -- some applications constantly freezing for a few seconds

Tags: 18.04, unity, nvidia, samba, thunderbird

I just upgraded my hardware and software:  moved from an AMD FX-8500 running Ubuntu 14.04 to a Ryzen 7 2700 with 32GB and a Samsung 970 EVO+ M2 drive.  I have a 4K monitor (3840 x 2160), with an NVIDIA GT1030 card, and I'm using NVIDIA's proprietary driver  (reported as version `390.116-0ubuntu0.18.04.1`)

I use Unity. (installed it after my first login, and then selected it for my user)

The OS and my home directory are on the local superfast M2 drive. Most of the working data is samba/cifs-mounted to a file server through a Gigabit LAN, two network switches away.  In case it could make a difference: the file server is running Debian 8.5, with samba version `4.2.14+dfsg-0+deb8u9`, and the Ubuntu machine runs cifs version `6.8-1`.

Now, several applications (mostly, Thunderbird and KiCAD 5.1.2) are constantly freezing (well, becoming unresponsive so that its window becomes "grayed out" by the OS or by Unity).

With Thunderbird, it happens rather constantly --- even with the window on the background, while I'm typing this message, every minute or so, I see the portion of the window that is visible turning "grayed out" for maybe 10 or 15 seconds;  whenever I try to do anything in it (e.g., click to select a different InBox, click on the "Get Messages" button, or "Get All Messages"), almost anything I try to do, the thing first freezes for 10 or 15 seconds before it does what I asked it to do).

Right now, for example, looking at Thunderbird freeze while I'm typing this message, I looked at the time, went and executed `sudo journalctl -xr`, and it shows nothing with timestamps during the period when Thunderbird was unresponsive.

With KiCAD, it's less frequent than Thunderbird, but still very frequent.

Now, I have Ubuntu 18.04 on three other machines (including a laptop), and don't experience these problems.  In any case, maybe "once every blue moon" they experience some trouble. BTW, one of these other machines also uses the same file server --- however, that machine (the "Media PC" in the living room) has neither Thunderbird nor KiCAD.

Does this ring a bell to someone that experienced similar problems? Suggestions on how to narrow-down / figure out the cause of the issue?

**[EDIT FOR ADDITIONAL INFO]:**

Outputs of `uname -a` on each of the machines (except the laptop --- don't have access to that one right now):

Problematic PC at home: `Linux <hostname> 4.18.0-20-generic #21~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed May 8 08:43:37 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`
(CPU is a Ryzen 7 2700)

Media PC at home: `Linux <hostname> 4.15.0-50-generic #54-Ubuntu SMP Mon May 6 18:46:08 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`
(CPU is an Athlon 5350 quad-core)

Worstation at work: `Linux <hostname> 4.15.0-47-generic #50-Ubuntu SMP Wed Mar 13 10:44:52 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`
(CPU is an Intel Core i7-4770K)

Video driver on the workstation at work is the same as on the problematic PC at home (`390.116-0ubuntu0.18.04.1`).

Commands executed on the problematic PC at home:

```
[···]$ free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            31G        4.6G         14G        589M         12G         25G
Swap:           32G          0B         32G

[···]$ vmstat -n 1
procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- -system-- ------cpu-----
 r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa st
 1  0      0 15037164 767408 12307416    0    0     0     2    2    3  0  0 99  0  0
 0  0      0 15037412 767408 12307416    0    0     0     0 2575 3315  0  0 99  0  0
 0  0      0 15037084 767408 12307416    0    0     0     0 2304 2864  0  0 99  0  0
 0  0      0 15037032 767408 12307416    0    0     0     0 2234 2949  0  0 99  0  0
 0  0      0 15036936 767408 12307416    0    0     0     0 2272 3079  0  0 99  0  0
 0  0      0 15037000 767408 12307416    0    0     0    60 2335 2991  0  0 100  0  0
^C
```

**[END EDIT]**

Comment: 1. What kernel versions are you using on each of your machines? 2. What video drivers are you using on each of them? 3. What happens when you switch to an open-source video driver? 4. What partition formats? 5. Output of `dmesg` from after a freeze? 6. Have you tried using `debsums` to verify that the problem apps have no corrupt files?

Comment: Edit your question and show me `free -h`. Does your Samsung SSD have the latest firmware installed? Does Nvidia version 430 support your card?

Comment: @heynnema -- NVIDIA 430 seems to support the GT1030 card  (as per a quick search through https://www.geforce.com/drivers).  Not sure about the SSD --- I guess I will check through the samsung support website.  I will edit the question to include the outputs of `free` and also `vmstat` (in case this one also could be helpful)

Comment: @xiota -- I will edit the question to show the kernel versions (I'm surprised to see they're not the same --- I keep all the machines up-to-date with security upgrades) and video drivers.  3) Whenever I've used the nouveau driver on either the old 14.094 PC at home or the machine at home, the performance has been horrific, so I stopped using that one.  All partitions are formatted ext4. 5) `dmesg` showed no entries corresponding to the time of a Thunderbird freeze that I tried this morning.  6) Seems unlikely, but it doesn't hurt to try  (I could even try `chkrootkit` or something like that)